# Index Match Array Formula with an OR condition

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a data frame that has a list of tasks with a Primary worker and secondary worker attached to the tasks.

e.g.,

```
**Job** | **Primary** | **Secondary**   
Sales | Bob | John  
Marketing | Jeff | Bob  
Management | Steve | John
```

My question is, how can I write an array formula to return a list of Jobs when Bob matches either Primary OR Secondary?

So far my formula works like this:

```
=(IF(ROWS(D$3:D3)<=$E$1,INDEX(Jobs!$A$2:$A$3,SMALL(OR(Jobs!$B$2:$B$3=$D$1,Jobs!$C$2:$C$3=$D$1,ROW(Jobs!$A$2:$A$3)-ROW(Jobs!$A$2)+1),ROWS(D$3:D3))),""))
```

...where D1 contains Bob's name and E1 contains a `COUNTIFS()` of the occurrences of his name in either column.

The answer I'm looking for in D3 and D4 respectively is "Sales, Marketing".

Let me know if you need any clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OR-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0) doesn't play well in array formulas as it is already a form of array processing.

Your formula is better as,

```
=IF(ROWS($3:3)<=$E$1,INDEX(Jobs!$A$1:$A$99, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$99)/SIGN((Jobs!$B$1:$B$99=$D$1)+(Jobs!$C$1:$C$99=$D$1)), ROWS($3:3))),"")
```

... or for pre-2010 as,

```
=IF(ROWS($3:3)<=$E$1,INDEX(Jobs!$A$1:$A$99, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$99)+((Jobs!$B$1:$B$99<>$D$1)*(Jobs!$C$1:$C$99<>$D$1))*1E+99, , ), ROWS($3:3))),"")
```

These are both standard formulas that do NOT require Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: Thanks! This works great. What if I wanted to include any primary or secondary that included Bob's name but maybe another person or extra text? e.g., If B2 = "Bob and Tom", how would I set up the formula to return any instance of Bob in either column. Right now I have =IF(ROWS($3:3)<=$E$1,INDEX(Jobs!$A$1:$A$99, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$99)/SIGN((Jobs!$B$1:$B$99="*"&$D$1&"*")+(Jobs!$C$1:$C$99="*"&$D$1&"*")), ROWS($3:3))),""), but that's not working.

Comment: Sorry but I am unclear. Do you want all the jobs that either Bob or Tom are either primary or secondary?

Comment: Just Bob. The desired answer would be the same as in OP. I'm wondering how it can find any instance of * Bob * in the columns, where * is the wildcard indicator. @Jeeped

Comment: That criteria would break this answer as it pertains to the original question asked but try [this](http://1drv.ms/1TVMM5J).

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.